# How to deal with a Pell's equation type problem with two primes

Tags: number-theory, pell-type-equations

I have some understanding of Pell's equation $$x^2-dy^2=1$$ where $d$ is a prime. I know that you can take the continued fraction of $\sqrt{d}$ and use information about the period and convergents to find things out. Now I need to show that if $p,q$ are primes $\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ then at least one of the equations $$px^2-qy^2=\pm 1$$ is soluble in integers $x,y$. I have not learned what to do when there is a prime in front of the $x^2$. How should I begin doing this?

Comment: Maybe this answer could help you https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1848077

Comment: Here's an idea, not a hint because I don't know whether it will work. The hypotheses on $p$ and $q$ say that neither is a quadratic residue of the other. Might that help?

Comment: That might help

Comment: There seems be an answer now at this duplicate question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2246651/show-that-if-p-and-q-are-primes-equiv-3mod-4-then-at-least-one-of-the

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048219

Comment: individ, that does not make sense to me. What does that have to do with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have a primitive solution to $x^2-pqy^2=1$ ($x$, $y$ positive, $y$ minimal). Then $x$ is odd and $y$ is even (think modulo $4$). Also
$$x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)=pqy^2$$
so that
$$\frac{x+1}2\frac{x-1}2=pq\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^2.$$
As $(x\pm 1)/2$ are coprime integers then we have one of the following

1. $(x+1)/2=u^2$, $(x-1)/2=pqv^2$
2. $(x+1)/2=pu^2$, $(x-1)/2=qv^2$
3. $(x+1)/2=qu^2$, $(x-1)/2=pv^2$
4. $(x+1)/2=pqu^2$, $(x-1)/2=v^2$

We succeed with (2) and (3) (write $1=(x+1)/2-(x-1)/2$). We eliminate
(1) by minimality to solution of Pell and (4) gives $v^2-pqu^2=-1$
which is impossible modulo $p$.

Comment: Copied from my answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2246651/show-that-if-p-and-q-are-primes-equiv-3mod-4-then-at-least-one-of-the

Comment: ??? The p is in the wrong spot on your answer.