# Continued Fraction of the Square Root of the Ratio of Two Primes $\equiv 3 \mod 4$

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions, pell-type-equations

I have been playing around with continued fractions, and I have noticed that if $p,q$ are two primes $\equiv 3 \mod 4$, then the continued fraction representation of $\sqrt{\frac{p}{q}}$ has an even period.

Now I know that exactly one of the equations $px^2 - qy^2 = \pm 1$ is solvable. And I also know that, for any $d\in\mathbb{N}$, $x^2 - d y^2 = 1$ is solvable and $x^2 - d y^2 = -1$ is solvable if and only if $\sqrt{d}$ has an odd period. Now I hope that I can make a connection here using the fact that either $px^2 - qy^2 = -1$ or $qy^2 - px^2 = -1$ is not solvable and the other one is. For example assume $qy^2 - px^2 = 1$ is solvable, then $qy^2 - px^2 = -1$ isn't. Then $y^2 - \frac{p}{q}x^2 = \frac{1}{q}$ is solvable and $y^2 - \frac{p}{q}x^2 = -\frac{1}{q}$ is not solvable. Now if $\frac{1}{q}$ was equal to $1$ and $\frac{p}{q}$ was an integer I could readily conclude that the continued fraction of  $\sqrt{\frac{p}{q}}$ has an even period, but these are not the case so I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: How do you know that $px^2 - q y^2 = \pm 1$   is solvable?

Comment: I know that exactly one of the cases $\pm 1$ is solvable. This question seems to be also asked in the site, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2245758/how-to-deal-with-a-pells-equation-type-problem-with-two-primes).

Comment: It might be more useful to examine the proof that $x^2 - dy^2 = -1$ is solvable if and only $\sqrt d$ has an odd period, and see if it can be adapted to the $px^2 - qy^2 = -1$ case.